# mootools vs jquery for web application

Tags: javascript, jquery, dojo, mootools

I have web application like registration for university and other work for university...

this is rich web application and basically we find it like desktop application... there is un suggestible feature and other things

i worked with jquery but some people suggest us some thing like mootools ( and also dojo ) for class simulator and other things

you thing which one better for my project and why?

also think about learn line for mootools for us and other things ... what we do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a dup.  Just search on jquery/mootools/dojo.  Without offering specific information on what you want a comparison on, you're probably just going to get a lot of answers based on personal bias.  Each toolkit has similar features at the core, but different programming styles, and vastly different features available in their plugin communities.

Answer (score 4):

almost features are alike between frameworks. And they are popular too so you can find solutions to get things done easily over the internet. I suggest choosing what you want after looking comparison between them [ Google for it, there are plenty of articles ], and I will give you a good website to start :

[DavidWalsh - Mootools developer](http://davidwalsh.name/)

Very clean and nice blog, although he is mootools developer but he also writes solutions in jquery and dojo.

Answer (score 3):

While I've been using jQuery a lot for the past couple of years, I've used MooTools in just two or three projects to make a good comparative...

But what I can tell is that 95% of the features is very much alike in both frameworks. I think jQuery have a slightly better DOM manipulation, while MooTools is a bit more robust in true client processing (JavaScript object modeling, inheritance, and so on).